# Spring return 401 with a duplicate entry on table SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES in logs

Tags: spring, session

We have a Projet Spring <--> Angular in Spring boot 3.1.1 ( we were in 3.0.1 and attempt update in case it was a bug )

In our website, only on a special page, we have some random disconnect.
Spring return a 401

In spring logs , we notice :

```
2023-08-08 14:30:44,549 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper [http-nio-8080-exec-47] No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2023-08-08 14:30:44,550 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMapping [http-nio-8080-exec-47] Mapped to com.ubipharm.cataloguepara.controller.back.SheetController#get(String, String, HttpSession)
2023-08-08 14:30:44,550 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper [http-nio-8080-exec-47] No session found by id: Caching result for getSession(false) for this HttpServletRequest.
2023-08-08 14:30:44,551 DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper [http-nio-8080-exec-47] A new session was created. To help you troubleshoot where the session was created we provided a StackTrace (this is not an error). You can prevent this from appearing by disabling DEBUG logging for org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.SESSION_LOGGER
java.lang.RuntimeException: For debugging purposes only (not an error)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:313)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:327)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:194)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:229)
        at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(WebUtils.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.setLocaleContext(SessionLocaleResolver.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleContextResolver.setLocale(LocaleContextResolver.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle(LocaleChangeInterceptor.java:125)
....
2023-08-08 14:30:44,564 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor [http-nio-8080-exec-46] Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-08-08 14:30:44,565 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor [http-nio-8080-exec-46] Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-08-08 14:30:44,566 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor [http-nio-8080-exec-46] Nothing to write: null body
2023-08-08 14:30:44,566 DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor [http-nio-8080-exec-46] Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2023-08-08 14:30:44,566 DEBUG o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet [http-nio-8080-exec-46] **Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED**
```

Sometimes it occurs also duplicate entry on the table SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES

The duplicate exception :

```
2023-08-08 15:23:54,710 DEBUG o.s.t.s.TransactionTemplate [http-nio-8080-exec-62] Initiating transaction rollback on application exception
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
]; (conn=33870) Duplicate entry '3f974714-8f57-4358-a609-bd3c6c2b7156-org.springframework.web....' for key 'PRIMARY'
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:251)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1538)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.insertSessionAttributes(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:561)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository$JdbcSession.lambda$save$11(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:912)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.lambda$executeWithoutResult$0(TransactionOperations.java:68)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
```

After many hours looking for any cause, it's two AJAX requests sent in same time to spring that sometimes raise this problem.

we try to update spring dependencies to last 3.1.1 from 3.0.2 but same problem.

I didn't find anothers that would have the same problem.

I seems to be a concurent access probleme with spring session...
Any idea ?

Thanks :-)

try to update spring from 3.0.2 to 3.1.1 in case it was a bug .

Answer (score 0):

This morning, I found it was the line in `SecurityConfig`

```
http.sessionManagement((session) -> session
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
```

Without it it works perfectly but it's not the first projet we had this line so finally can"t really explain the real reason of the problem....